# How to get explode data in codeginter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, explode

i have some problem in getting data based on explode.

Example if i have an array with `$cuisines_category`:

`string(26) "Breakfast/Cake - Accept voucher/New Restaurant""`

from that array it was has 2 content data which `Breakfast/Cake` as `$cuisines_name_all` and the `Accept voucher/New_Restaurant` as `$facility_name_all`.

So far i can return the explode data, which this following code :

```
$split=array_map('trim', explode("-",$cuisines_category));
$cuisines_name_all = (isset($split[0]) === TRUE ? $split[0] : 0);
$facility_name_all = (isset($split[1]) === TRUE ? $split[1] : 0);

$cuisines_name = explode("/", $cuisines_name_all);
$facility_name = explode("/", $facility_name_all);
```

My problem is, how about if the array `$cuisines_category` content just for `$facility_name_all` as this array:

`string(30) "Online payment available/Deals"`

so i change my explode code with this code :

```
$split=array_map('trim', explode("-",$cuisines_category));
$cuisines_name_all = (isset($split[0]) === TRUE ? $split[0] : 0);
if(isset($split[1])){
    $facility_name_all = $split[1];
}else{
    $facility_name_all = $split[0];
}

$cuisines_name = explode("/", $cuisines_name_all);
$facility_name = explode("/", $facility_name_all);
```

Yes i can return the `$facility_name`, but the `$cuisines_name` has same content with `$facility_name` which `$cuisines_name` should be not have any content

Because i need to return that `$cuisines_name` and `$facility_name` for getting a new data from database.

guys do you know how to different the data if implode`-` doesn't exit?

Comment: in the second case what is expected outcome?

Comment: sorry i dont clear what u trying to said. can you more explain @Anant

Comment: `string(30) "Online payment available/Deals"`  in this case what is your expected outcome in term of  `$facility_name` and `$cuisines_name`?

Comment: @anant is should be only `$facility_name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you are looking?

**Scenario 1**

```
$cuisines_category = "Breakfast/Cake - Accept voucher/New Restaurant";

$split = array_map('trim', explode("-", $cuisines_category));

$cuisines_name_all = (count($split) > 1 ) ? $split[0] : 0;
$facility_name_all = (count($split) > 1 ) ? $split[1] : $split[0];

$cuisines_name = explode("/", $cuisines_name_all);
$facility_name = explode("/", $facility_name_all);
```

**Output**

```
cuisines_name: Array ( [0] => Breakfast [1] => Cake )

facility_name: Array ( [0] => Accept voucher [1] => New Restaurant )
```

---

**Scenario 2**

```
$cuisines_category = "Accept voucher/New Restaurant";

$split = array_map('trim', explode("-", $cuisines_category));

$cuisines_name_all = (count($split) > 1 ) ? $split[0] : 0;
$facility_name_all = (count($split) > 1 ) ? $split[1] : $split[0];

$cuisines_name = explode("/", $cuisines_name_all);
$facility_name = explode("/", $facility_name_all);
```

**Output**

```
cuisines_name: Array ( [0] => 0 )

facility_name: Array ( [0] => Accept voucher [1] => New Restaurant )
```

Comment: and how about if `$cuisines_category` it just contain for `$cuisines_name_all`?

Comment: No it won't work then. cuisines name will go into `facility_name` array. In the question you mentioned two possibilities, 1. string contains both cuisines names and facility names 2. only facility name is there.

Comment: Now if your string can contain both facility and cuisine or either one of them, then in your string you have to add type also. Because, right now there is no way we can detect is it cuisine or facility.

Comment: thank you, so the one way to put `-` visible even if i add one of  facility or cuisines

Comment: If that string is created by you then why don't you create string something like this `"cuisine: Breakfast/Cake - facility: Accept voucher/New Restaurant"` and while fetching we can write program accordingly. This way your code will become more robust.